# Trying to Use dplyr Complete() Function in Snowflake

Tags: r, dplyr, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to fill in missing dates in my data. In dplyr while processing records in-memory I am able to use complete() function to fill in dates in rows that have missing data. I provide the min and max dates and I get a complete list of dates. I have large amounts of data so I would rather not use collect() to process them all in-memory to use complete() and join with rest of data. I was wondering how I can do this while using tables from Snowflake and if there's an equivalent function for complete() in Snowflake. Here's my code:

```
  df_agg_all <- df_agg %>%  
    collect() %>%
    complete(SHIP_DATE = seq(min(SHIP_DATE), max(SHIP_DATE),
                             by='1 week')) %>%
```

Comment: Generating the pernament calendar table or subquery could be used. Related: [Calculate number of specific days between dates in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69575634/calculate-number-of-specific-days-between-dates-in-snowflake)